# Sidekiq perform_async not queueing some jobs

Tags: ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

Currently have a worker calling perform_async that randomly doesn't queue jobs. 9 out of 10 times it works...but it occasionally just doesn't queue the job. The job id gets created, but we never see it get enqueued and it doesn't run. When we notice this happens we simply rerun the job in the heroku console and it runs as it should. When the job actually runs, it works fine. The problem is that it doesn't always run.

some stats: rails 4.1.11, ruby 2.2.3, sidekiq 4.0.2, redis 2.8.21
puma and heroku

From the sidekiq reliability wiki, it states that there are three issues related to reliability: sending jobs to redis, getting jobs out of redis and scheduling.

We're having trouble identifying why this job isn't getting queued in redis. Stumped and was hoping someone could make a suggestion about how:

1. Best way to monitor whether the job gets enqueued? Is using the sidekiq api the best way to do this?
2. What are some of the (what's the range of) reasons why a job might not make it to redis?
3. What's the best way to ensure reliability going forward?
4. If the job isn't getting to redis, why wouldn't sidekiq recognize that and give us some kind of error / feedback.

In case it helps, here's our RedisToGo config:

```
# = General     
port 10655
databases 1

loglevel notice
logfile /mnt/redis.306247.log

# = Security 
requirepass xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


# = Limits 
maxmemory 52428800
maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
maxmemory-samples 3

maxclients 128
timeout 150

dir /home/redis/10655

appendonly yes
appendfilename appendonly.aof
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no

hash-max-ziplist-entries 64
hash-max-ziplist-value 512

list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64

set-max-intset-entries 512

zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64

activerehashing yes

# = LUA Scripting 
lua-time-limit 5000

# = Client Limits 
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit slave 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible you are running a unique jobs plugin which is cancelling the push to Redis?

Comment: @MikePerham Hi Mike. Thanks for the quick reply. We are not using any ancillary plugin related to uniqueness. Any other potential causes that come to mind?

Comment: Side note: using a `volatile-lru` policy for Sidekiq is not a good idea.  You should use `noeviction` as you cannot evict any Sidekiq data safely.

Comment: You can use `redis-cli monitor` to see the actual Redis commands being executed by your server.  You should see a job pushed to Redis this way.  Are you using Sidekiq Pro?  Otherwise I can't think of a reason why perform_async would return a JID but not actually push to Redis.

Comment: @MikePerham we are now! Hopefully Sidekiq Pro will help. Thanks again.

Comment: Seems to be happening to me too. But for me almost every time only one of the two jobs get executed. PS: These 2 jobs are enqueued in a single request. i.e. at almost the same time. Not using sidekiq pro.